# opening pdf file in console app

Tags: c#

Is there a way to have my console app open my PDF file (in my default application for PDFs) given a byte array?

Comment: Can you be more precise what "open" means? Do you want to open the PDF in the default application for .pdf files, e.g. open it in Adobe Reader?

Comment: ... And if that is the case, the easiest way would probably be to save it, then use Process.Start to execute the users default PDF reader.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to open the PDF in the default application you will have to save it first to a temporary location:

```
byte[] buffer = GetPdfData();

// save to temp file
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".pdf");
File.WriteAllBytes(path, buffer);

// open in default PDF application
Process process = Process.Start(path);
process.WaitForExit();

// clean up temp file
File.Delete(path);
```

Comment: nice answer, would you need to save the file with a .PDF extension for it to work?

Comment: @Gabriel: Good point, I already fixed it while you wrote your comment.