# How to generate a report in PDF and DOC with Console Application?

Tags: c#, pdf, console, report, doc

I want to generate a report by the Console Application to DOC and PDF how can I do this?

Comment: Just use this tool and that utility. Seriously. A report of what? What did you try? Did you Google a little? There are a plethora of libraries to generate PDF and DOC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:[Itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990198/opening-pdf-file-in-console-app)

ITextSharp is a library used to create PDF documents. It provides all of the primitive functions necessary to create a PDF document. However, since all of the methods are based on primitive operations, it is easy to confuse the look and feel of a document without enforcing certain standards. This helper class provides two key benefits. First, it simplifies the creation of PDF documents. Second, it helps enforce standards in terms of the look and feel of a document.